# How can I implement a work-around for the let block?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Reading the [second chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md) of [Kyle Simpson's ES6 & Beyond book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/es6%20%26%20beyond) I see an example for a **let block**:

```
let (a = 2, b, c) {
    // ..
}
```

yet, if I execute this in my browser, it throws the error of

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

It does not work even in https://babeljs.io

So, this syntax was not yet implemented. My question is as follows: can I achieve this syntax or something very similar to it?

Comment: *... experimental (not standardized) form of the `let` declaration ...* — you can always just use a plain block with a `let` declaration at the top.

Comment: Also, check [Scope And Closures - Appendix B](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/apB.md) for a [transpiling tool](https://github.com/getify/let-er) developed by the author.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote? I believe this is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (non-standard) syntax you're referring to was implemented in [JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#New_features_in_JavaScript_1.7), which [shipped with Firefox 2.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/2).

[Version 44](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/44#JavaScript) of Firefox [removed this syntax](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/10/14/breaking-changes-let-const-firefox-nightly-44/) to make the implementation of `let` and `const` compliant with ES6 ([bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1023609)). Before that these extensions had been deprecated since [Firefox 36](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/36#JavaScript).

Workaround:

```
{
    let a = 2, b, c;
    // ..
}
```